# How to repair (and prevent) pool cover tear & holes

Tags: safety, pool

We have a safety cover for an inground pool. Over the winter, heavy snow melting and refreezing caused it to be weighed below the surface and tore up a few holes where the cover contacts the concrete edge. A safety cover seems pretty expensive. **Are there ways to repair these? Any tricks to prevent such friction-caused tears?**

[image: cover hole 1]
[image: cover hole 2]

Comment: A local pool company probably has repair kits.  Most likely vinyl patches with glue.  The concrete edge of a pool should be quite smooth or did the cover catch on something(ice)?  Check what the cover is made from, if pool company is very expensive for kits.

Comment: Yes, the edges have smooth plastic flashing, but I suspect rocks or whatever were stopped at the flashing and the heavy ice pulled the middle of the cover downwards, rubbing these hard objects. There were white-ish lines at the four sides of the pool cover from rubbing the pool edges and almost all holes were on these lines.